# UINavigationBar inside UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have some static cells that I want to display, so I have a UITableViewController. There is also a NavigationBar in this scene that contains some buttons at the top. The setup looks like this:

[image: UITableViewController setup]

If I had a UIViewController that contained a UITableView in it, the setup would look like:

[image: UIViewController setup]

So, the question is:

- Why does the Navigation Bar have to be embedded inside the UITableView when using a UITableViewController? (I have tried putting it elsewhere but IB won't let me)
- I know that UITableView is a subclass of UIView, but is it OK that the top level element in the hierarchy is not a View (but a TableView)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to use a `UINavigationBar` in iOS:

- Embedded inside a `UINavigationController` (recommended)
- As a standalone object

For your particular situation, I'd recommend that you put your `UITableViewController` as the `rootViewController` of a `UINavigationController`. That way you automatically get a navigation bar which you can customize according to your needs. In a typical user experience, when you tap some of your table view rows a new view controller will be pushed onto the navigation stack, so you'll probably end up needing a navigation controller anyway.

What if you decide to use a navigation bar as a standalone object? This is perfectly fine, you can use it inside a view hierarchy as an ordinary `UIView`, but you'll need to create another object that implements the `UINavigationBarDelegate` protocol and set it as the `delegate` property of your navigation bar. If you use a `UINavigationController` the delegate is already set and configured for you. You also need to add/remove navigation items (instances of `UINavigationItem`) to your navigation bar by using the `pushNavigationItem:animated:` and `popNavigationItemAnimated:` methods.

And about your question on the view hierarchy, you can use a `UITableView` anywhere a `UIView` is required. The only caveat is that a `UITableView` is a view hierarchy on its own and that may restrict your layout a little bit.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be placing your `UINavigationBar` in your `UITableView`. You should be putting your `UITableViewController` in a `UINavigationController`, because that will provide a `UINavigationBar` for you.

So if you select your `UITableViewController` in the storyboard, you can choose Embed In -> Navigation Controller from the Editor menu. This would be the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The way a UITableViewController works, is its root view is a UITableView. So there is no way to put the UINavigationBar anywhere other than in the UITableView.

I tend never to use a UITableViewController as it doesn't really give you much.

If you particularly want to use the UITableViewController, I don't believe that there is any real problem in having the navigation bar within the table view. You just need to make sure that you set the contentInset on the table view such that the navigation bar doesn't block the content. Though it seems a bit backward to do it this way.

My recommendation would be to just use a normal UIViewController with a navigation bar and a table view.

If you actually need functional navigation, you need to put your UITableViewController within a UINavigationController.

Hope this helps :)

Let me know if anything is still unclear.

Comment: Generally you wouldn't want to do it this way. If you want a navigation bar, use a UINavigationController, even if you aren't going to be pushing additional controllers.

Comment: If you don't want navigation, and you know you will never want it, I don't see any reason not to do it this way. The UINavigationController won't give you anything, other than extra quirks that come standard with UIKit elements :P

Comment: What quirks do you speak of? It's almost always better to use a UINavigationController to include a UINavigationBar, unless you plan on doing some special customization that UINavigationController doesn't allow, which it doesn't appear is the case here. Besides, there are benefits to using a UITableViewController as opposed to a UIViewController with an embedded UITableView, and that approach would require using a UINavigationController to properly get the UINavigationBar.